# Issue with dynamic resource allocation in Apache Spark running on Kubernetes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kubernetes, parallel-processing, bigdata

I'm encountering an issue with dynamic resource allocation in Apache Spark where the number of executors doesn't scale up as expected, even though the workload increases significantly. We're using Spark in a dynamic environment with varying workloads, and we expect the cluster to scale up and down automatically based on demand.

Here's a brief overview of our setup:

We've enabled dynamic resource allocation in our Spark configuration with parameters like:

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors 
spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors
```

We're running Spark v 3.4.0 on a 15 node Kubernetes Cluster.

The workload varies over time, with peaks and valleys in processing requirements.

Despite configuring dynamic allocation settings, we're noticing that the number of executors remains static and doesn't scale up when the workload increases beyond a certain threshold. This results in longer processing times and underutilization of resources during peak periods.

We've tried adjusting the dynamic allocation parameters and monitoring resource usage but haven't been able to resolve the issue.

Here's a snippet of our current Spark configuration:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
.setAppName("Pipeline1")
.setMaster("k8s://https://<hostname>:<port>")
.set("spark.executor.instances", "10")
.set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
.set("spark.executor.cores", "4")
.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
.set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true")
.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors", "2")
.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", "20")
.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors", "5")

val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()
```

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!